# Instrumentation Test not starting on Android only on a real device. Working on Simulator

Tags: react-native, detox, android-instrumentation

I am mainly facing an issue with running detox tests on android real device. The main problem I face is that `await device.launchApp()` just doesn't launch the app. After adding some log traces I see that android instrumentation command is the one that is not actually starting the app. Detox internally calls the command `/Users/<uname>/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -s 39bc3158 shell am instrument -w -r -e detoxServer ws://localhost:51414 -e detoxSessionId 5c04ed58-aa77-64bb-aa2b-3a008f21ac2b -e debug false com.realapp.app.test/androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner`. This command hangs and Process Times out after sometime and doesn't launch the app.

If I create an instrumentation test from android studio also I am seeing the same issue and this problem only occurs on a real device and not on a simulator. Simulator works absolutely fine and the test cases run smooth.

I have looked into different issues, used 4.1.2 android studio, Invalidated cached and restarted upgraded to latest beta android studio and nothing seems to help.

Also the instrumentation tests run fine on the real device if i open the app manually after starting the tests. The tests are just not launching the app automatically.